# Quering XElements for children with children attributes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Here is the XML outline:

```
<Root> 
  <Thing att="11">    
    <Child lang="e">  
       <record></record>
       <record></record>
       <record></record>  
   </Child >
   <Child lang="f">  
       <record></record>  
       <record></record>                
       <record></record>
   </Child > 
 </Thing> 
</Root>
```

I have the following:

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                 .GetManifestResourceStream(FileName));

   var data = XElement.Load(reader);
foreach (XElement single in Data.Elements())
 {
      // english records
      var EnglishSet = (from e in single.Elements("Child")
         where e.Attribute("lang").Equals("e")
        select e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But I'm getting back nothing. I want to be able to for Each "Thing" select the "Child" where the attribute "lang" equals a value.

I have also tried this, which has not worked.

```
var FrenchSet = single.Elements("Child")
.Where(y => y.Attribute("lang").Equals("f"))
.Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking whether the `XAttribute` object is equal to the string `"e"`.
Since an `XAttribute` object is never equal to a string, it doesn't work.

You need to check the `XAttribute` object's `Value`, like this:

```
where y => y.Attribute("lang").Value == "e"
```

Comment: +1 for faster than me by 2 minutes, but you haven't mentioned the second point that I have (and Stephan too).

Comment: Thanks. I knew that it was something small. Always is. 
Which format is the best to use: Method based or query based?

Comment: @Arnej65 Query based gets translated to methods by the compiler, so use which over method is easier for you to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the attribute object with the string "e", rather than the value of the attrbute object. You're also returning the value of the node rather than the node. Since the value is empty, you'll just get the empty string.

Try this instead:

```
var EnglishSet = (from e in single.Elements("Child")
                  where e.Attribute("lang").Value == "e"
                  select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var EnglishSet = (from e in single.Elements("Child")
         where e.Attribute("lang").Value.Equals("e")
        select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

As Slaks stated you were checking that the attribute not it's value was "e".  You also don't need `select e.Value` because the "Child" nodes don't have a value they have "record" children.

Comment: True true. I'm getting all the data in "record" and not the nodes.